# Pasting to Anaconda Prompt is slow

Tags: python, anaconda

When I paste a piece of code into Anaconda prompt, it generates letter by letter and for large pieces of code takes a long time. Is there a way to speed this up? I thought it used to be instantaneous. Did something change?

EDIT 2:
I don't usually use cmd.exe or PowerShell.exe when I'm coding in python; however, I gave it a shot and it was very fast. The slow paste is only happening when I've started python in the Anaconda Prompt. I tried pasting into Anaconda Prompt before I started a script and the paste was very fast, as well. To demonstrate:

From Anaconda Prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\rschult4>
```

Pasting above is fast. But pasting below is slow:

```
(base) C:\Users\rschult4>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
```

EDIT:

OS:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Also:

```
(base) C:\Users\rschult4>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\rschult4\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\rschult4\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\rschult4\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\rschult4\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\rschult4\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\rschult4\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Please add on which OS are you running Anaconda.

Comment: Is it slow in both powerShell.exe and cmd.exe?

Comment: @AndrewQ Added edits to address these inquiries. Any ideas what's going on??

Comment: @rjt Added edits to address these inquiries. Any ideas what's going on??

Comment: python is interpreting the code as it is pasted in?   I normally write code to a file.py and run `python file.py` Wondering what the use-case is to copy and paste large chunks of code.   Try `choco install python3` and run a more native version of python.  Or paste a large chunk of code into the Ubuntu for Windows bash shell or into a real ssh session at a remote linux box.  If those options do not exhibit the problem, then anaconda is to blame.

Comment: Right, the issue is definitely something to do with the anaconda prompt but only once I've ran Python. When python is running, I paste some code that I'm currently developing and waiting for the code to paste takes too long. I like to paste because on the front end of the script I have to load so much data that rerunning it every time I need to debug some code takes too long as well.